# Azure Functions: No authentication handlers are registered error message even though all methods are set to AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

**General info**

- Azure Function v4
- Running in-process model
- Consumption plan

The host.json:

```json
 {
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I diagnose my Azure Function application I can see these errors in the logs which I think is responsible for the app going down a few minutes a day. The error message and stack:

```
Full Exception :
 System.InvalidOperationException : No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("ArmToken",...)?
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context,String scheme)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy,HttpContext context)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(??)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(??)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(??)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.FunctionInvocationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at /_/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Middleware/FunctionInvocationMiddleware.cs : 41
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at /_/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Middleware/ExceptionMiddleware.cs : 27
```

All of our functions are set to a Anonymous Authorization level, and we don't have anything in the startup which indicates that I want to add authorization in some way. Here's the startup class:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(X.Startup))]
namespace X
{
    public class Startup : XFunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                // Gender 0 => "Female"
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                // reduce payload
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The function is up and running 99% of the time, but sometimes we get these 502 errors which I think is because the host dies. Do you have any idea where this error can come from?

I've tried to change from AddControllers to AddMvc because I read that the AddControllers calls the AddAuthorization method, but without any luck.

Comment: Provide the code from `host.json`, function declaration in the function class - that helps to diagnose the issue more

Comment: @TheMassacre I've edited the original post and added the host.json.
 All the functions are declared this way:
 [FunctionName(nameof(GetFavouriteClubs))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFavouriteClubs(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "v1/Persons/FavouriteClubs")] HttpRequest req)

But with different routes of course.

Comment: Add this attribute `[Authorize]` before the FunctionName line and try.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my environment with the below code and configuration, it worked as expected.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {           options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
  options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**.Csproj:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

[image]

- If still doesn't work, try adding the below code in startup.cs:

```cs
          builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            })
.AddIdentityCookies();
```

Comment: Yes, as I stated in the original post, the application is up and running 99% of the time and then occasionally we get those exceptions. I've never got the exception when I'm debugging locally.

Comment: Did you try deleting bin folder and rebuilding the project?